# Understanding 分かる in this sentence

Tags: reading-comprehension

> 警察庁によると、このテストで「認知症」という脳の病気の可能性があると言われた人は約１年で５万７０９９人いました。**そして、この中の１８９２人が、医者が調べて認知症だとわかりました。**
>   According to the police, in this test, in around 1 year, there were 57099 people who were told that they might have a brain disease called dementia. 1892 of these people *knew they had dementia because a doctor had tested them*.

I'm having trouble understanding the sentence in bold. The translation is my best guess. My understanding of 分かる is a bit shaky. Does this sentence suggest that the 1892 people already knew they had dementia **before** they took the police test, or does it imply that those people went to the doctor **after** the police test and were then confirmed as having dementia? (putting aside the fact that a person diagnosed with dementia might still not *know* they have dementia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This わかる is close to 判明する(become clear) rather than "know". So この中の１８９２人が、医者が調べて認知症だとわかりました means "It became clear that 1892 of these people had dementia because a doctor had tested them."

We can't know why they took police test and when they knew they had dementia just from this sentence.

Comment: 自動車運転免許更新の簡易検査に引っかかったのが年５万、うち二次検査に回って認知症の判定が出たのが年１８９２ってことじゃないですかね。

Comment: そうですね。その可能性は高いです。

Comment: @YuuichiTam Is この中の１８９２人が the subject of だ? I had assumed it was the subject of わかりました.

Comment: I think so. This structure is "We knew that 1892 of these people had dementia".